# remastering knoppix: which version and what method should i use

Tags: linux, livecd, knoppix

I'd like to remaster knoppix (mainly add and configure some software). I downloaded newest version (KNOPPIX-ADRIANE_V6.2CD-2009-11-18-EN.iso) but later i read that it has some other window manager as default, not kde... and i want to have kde on my remaster. Is kde included on that iso but it's not default or it's not included at all? If it's not there what knoppix version should i get for my remaster?

My other question... I've seen some remastering scripts (with menus, etc) on knoppix forums, do any of these works with version i have? Or with version i should have if i need kde?

Answer (score 1):

Knoppix has sort of fallen off the wagon in the past couple years, they went to a whole new system (one of their releases, I think 6.0, if you booted with default settings, you didn't even get a GUI!!), and it's just not updated that often anymore. I'd suggest looking at other available LiveCDs. Sorry I can't give a specific suggestion, but I know there are many out there (For example Ubuntu has one). See [LiveCDlist.com](http://www.livecdlist.com/) as a quick overview. No idea how complete this is, but it does have a whole bunch of them.

Comment: Hmmm i would prefer it to not be ubuntu. Can be debian based, but rather not ubuntu please. If anyone has any suggestions - go on :)

Comment: Check out http://www.livecdlist.com/

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to make your own customized little distro, check out [SUSE Studio](http://susestudio.com/). They allow you to install whatever software you want (this includes KDE), and even test drive it remotely!

[image]

You may also be interested in [Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/). If you are familiar with the internals you should have no problem setting up a customized distribution.

Comment: suse studio is just lame. sorry. and i need to wait for invite. and probably they will want me to pay at some point. huh. when i was talking about making live distro i was thinking about something more traditional... you know... command line? ever heard about command line? ;)

Comment: If you care to check out the linux badge ( http://superuser.com/badges/50/linux ) you'll see I'm the only one with it as of yet. I think I know what the command line is :) But why would you need KDE then? Added another option to my answer.